# Flowing Monk + Reposition

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I have a couple of questions regarding the flowing monks Redirection ability and utilizing combat maneuvers as attacks of opportunity.

**Flowing Monk**

> At first level, as an immediate action, a flowing monk can attempt a reposition or trip combat maneuver against a creature that the flowing monk threatens and attacks him.

**Special Attacks / Combat Maneuvers:**

> This section discusses all of the various standard maneuvers you can perform during combat other than normal attacks, casting spells, or using other class abilities. Some of these special attacks can be made as part of another action (such as an attack) or as an attack of opportunity.

It is from my understanding that one can make a trip or sunder attempt as an attack of opportunity. The rules state that combat maneuvers are treated as single attacks and attacks of opportunity provoke 'single attacks'. 
**Can reposition be made as an attack of opportunity?** 
**If so how would that work if an opponent tries to move past you?**
 **Scenario:**

- Opponent may move 6 spaces and steps into the flowing monks threatened square as their first move
- The second move they provoke but the flowing monk does not utilize the attack of opportunity just yet
- The third move the flowing monk makes the attack and beats the opponents CMD by 5 allowing him to reposition the opponent 10ft
- The flowing monk moves the opponent 10 ft back leaving them back to where they stood after the first 5ft step.

At this point the opponent has used up 15ft but has only progressed 5. 
**Does the opponent stop moving from this point?**
If the monk was of 8th level would he be able to use both a maneuver and trip ability as mentioned: "*at 8th level, a flowing monk can make both a reposition and a trip maneuver as part of a single immediate action with this ability*" Or does that only apply when he is being attached?

**Does the redirection count towards the opponents total movement that round?**
In the scenario above, the creature moved 15ft, was redirected 10ft, do they have 5ft left of movement? Or 15ft?
**Final Question, does a mounted unit inherit the size of their mount when provoking attacks of opportunities through ride by attacks?**
I ask this one because it states that most combat maneuvers cannot be made against creatures of a higher size category. Combat maneuvers like trip would make sense, you would only be 'tripping' the mount. However if my opponent was targeting a friendly PC behind me and provokes an attack of opportunity from me. Am I able to use a Reposition maneuver against the 'rider' not the mount! (A medium sized creature riding upon a large mount). If so would I be able to throw him from his horse or would that fall under "*You cannot use this maneuver to move a foe into a space that is intrinsically dangerous, such as a pit or wall of fire.*"

Comment: Your post seems to confuse immediate actions and attacks of opportunities -- they're different things!  The flowing monk's ability doesn't use AoO at all.

Comment: The question was directed at the reposition. So in the example of a horse run-by, should the rider choose to attack it would then utilize the monks immediate action, that I understand. This was more or less a series of questions that would stem should one be able to make a reposition as an attack of opportunity.

Comment: Typically attacking a rider involves threatening the square the rider is assumed to be in - for a horse, 5' vertical reach and threatening any of the horse's squares should definitely be enough.  So if a horse rider moves through your threatened squares, you should technically get two AoOs - one against the rider, and one against the horse.  Additionally, Greater Improved Trip is what would let you use Flowing Monk to get a free attack.

Comment: Oh yes, I was going to combo that with the Vicious Stomp feat so that I could make two attacks of opportunity. Though I believe the rules state that you cannot make more than 1 attack of opportunity per action that provokes, thus I think that you would not be able to attack both the rider and the horse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you may not use reposition in an AoO in this manner, only trip, sunder, and disarm.  Read the SRD rules on combat maneuvers, they each have a specified action type they can replace.  For those three it is "an attack" but for reposition it is a standard action, http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Reposition

Your flowing monk ability is completely separate, and procs on someone attacking you - then you can trip, or trip+reposition.

To get the AoO they'd have to provoke one normally, like by moving out of a threatened square, and to provoke the "flow" they would have to attack you - not an impossible combo especially if you have reach, but uncommon.

Reposition does not count against their move, but tripping certainly stops their movement.

The horse part is unclear and probably a separate question anyway.

Comment: Okay thanks! That answered most of the questions. The horse one would be at the dms discretion anyway.